# Force Yum to install despite missing dependencies

Tags: yum

Is it possible to force a `yum` installation despite missing dependencies?

I know it is possible to do that with `rpm` but so far I couldn't find any `yum` magic.

Comment: No. A main goal of `yum` is to put an automatic dependency solver on top of `rpm` - breaking dependency chains by forcing a package install (or removal) while ignoring dependencies makes it kinda pointless.

Comment: @Brian Make sense. Is there a concept of 'required'/'recommended' deps?

Comment: Not yet; that is currently in development. What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The RPM for Cassandra has a dependency on Python 2.7 which I don't have on the system (CERN Scientific Linux - Red Hat version). However Cassandra doesn't need Python2.7 for itself, just for the database shell, which is usually run on another machine (where I'll have 2.7). That's really annoying.